# Rendering Excel files In Browser Through Office Online via WOPI Protocol

Tags: excel, ms-office, ms-wopi, office-online-server

We are planning to integrate with Office Online to render Excel files in browser. I understood the overall workflow by going through the documentation but I have a few questions:

1. Is the excel file rendering responsive on mobile (both android & iOS)? I understand the file rendering is responsive when viewed in the excel mobile app but the question is mainly about rendering it inside our app which is a hybrid (cordova based - web view) app.
2. Can we install Office Online server on-premise when using it for rendering excel files in production mode?
3. Do we need to implement authentication given that the application from which the user clicks on the file has authentication mechanism already in place? In this context a related question is do we need to generate access tokens?
4. If we go with the Office online server deployment in the microsoft cloud, would it be a dedicated server deployed for our needs? Would it be scalable based on the server load?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. The mobile web experience is not perfect but it's possible to open and view the files in the browser without bigger issues.
2. What do you mean by "production mode"? You can install and use it as long as you comply with the license terms (which is basically that every editor needs to have their own Office license).
3. Yes, you need to use `access_token`-based authorization, if you want your files secured. The URLs of the files served by a WOPI host are usually pretty easy to guess so if there is not `access_token`, anyone can see them.
4. Do you  mean [Office Cloud Storage Partner Program](https://dev.office.com/programs/officecloudstoragepartnerprogram) or just deploying OOS to MS Azure? If the latter, then the architecture is entirely up to you. You can deploy the servers into a [farm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/deploy-office-online-server#deploy-the-office-online-server-farm) to make the infrastructure scalable enogh.

Comment: 1. Ok. I take it as a yes that the excel files could be reading inside a third party app.There is [separate](https://dev.office.com/programs/officecloudstoragepartnerprogram) partner program for it too. 
2. I was under the impression that the office online server could be installed on-premise only for testing. I didn't follow the last statement. The licensing is based on the number of editors that are opened by the users at a given time?
3. Ok
4. I was referring to the partner program. Related to #2, does it mean that OOS could not be deployed on a private cloud?

Comment: 2,4) OK, I was talking about the standalone installation of OOS. I'm not aware of the license terms of the Office Cloud Storage Program... However, afaik you'll be given access to testing environment. The whole testing/go live process is described [here](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_test_ship/shipping.html#shipping).